# How to increase Windows 10 Display settings, resolution change timout?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, timeout

I need to change the number of screens and their screen resolutions frequently in Windows 10. When I do so, I get a message that asks "Keep these display settings?", and if not confirmed within 15 seconds, it will switch back to the old configuration.

Sometimes, depending on the physical displays used, this timeout period is too short, and I would like to enhance it. Where can this timout period be set to a longer timeout, like for example 30 seconds until the old settings are reverted?

Thank you.

Comment: You could consider using a third-party program that doesn't even show the confirmation. I don't know all programs, but I use ActualTools Window Manager (paid) that has the ability to setup desktop profiles and it can change the resolution. It will not ask confirmation when doing so.

Answer (score 4):

**Regedit global setting:**

You can change message time globally in register.
However, this will change duration of all time-limited monits in system.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility 
MessageDuration
```

**Customer Windows external applications:**

For all versions of Windows you can download external apps. I.e:

- create AutoHotkey script
- use PowerShell module [DisplaySetting](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DisplaySettings/0.0.2)
- download and execute [QRes](https://pureinfotech.com/change-screen-resolution-command-line-windows-10/)

**Windows Server built-in CMD:**

This system has built in setres.exe and PS ServerCore class so you can use command line natively.

Comment: +1 nice answer. :)

Comment: I confirm it works, but you need to restart first (Windows 10, May 2023) . Initially the decimal value was 5, I changed it to 30 and it worked after restart.